# Как заполнить двумерный массив строками из файла? C#

Tags: c#, массивы

Имеется текстовый документ, заполненный таблицой неправильных глаголов вида

- to be was, were been быть
- become became become становиться

итд

Как заполнить двумерный массив этой таблицей так, чтобы он имел вид:

```
string[,] verbs = 
                {
                    {"to be" , "was, were", "been", "быть"},
                    {"become", "became", "become", "становиться"}
                      ...
                };
```

Comment: У тебя между глаголами в строке есть какой-нибудь делитель , yапример, запятая ?

Comment: Нету, потому что строка "was, were" имеет запятую и программа запишет две строки вместо одной. Но можно добавить другой разделитель,например точку

Comment: Я ниже решение написал, попробуй его. Просто замени запятую на любой желаемый делитель в коде.

Comment: мне же нужен двумерный массив а не список

Comment: Вам реально нужен список, поверьте. Двумерный массив в вашей ситуации очень неудобная штука.

Comment: спасибо,попробую воспользоваться,ну а все же, если мне нужен именно двумерный массив?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно вот так вот, при условии того, что делителем является запятая.

```
 string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);//считываем все строки в массив
            List<string[]> res = new List<string[]>();
            foreach (var line in readText)//перебираем строки массива
            {
                res.Add(line.Split(','));//Каждую строку сплитим и помещаем в список массивов.
            }
```

Если обойтись без списка, то будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
    string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);//считываем все строки в массив
    string[][] res=new string[readText.Length][];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var line in readText)//перебираем строки массива
    {
        res[i] = line.Split(',');
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: А как обратиться к первому элементу списка, а в нем к третьей строке?

Comment: Так же как и в двумерном массиве res[0][2]